# Adding a Azure AD User to a group using Rest (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rest, azure, sharepoint

I am new with rest and I'm trying to Add a Azure Ad User to a specific group and I get bad request, can anyone help me see what I'm doing wrong...

My code is this:

```
        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

        // Specify values for the following required parameters
        queryString["api-version"] = "1.6";
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authString, false);
        ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientID, clientSecret);
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resAzureGraphAPI, clientCred);
        // Specify values for path parameters (shown as {...})
        var uri = serviceRootURL + "/groups/" + "software developer" +"/$links/members" + "?" + queryString;

        HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        endpointRequest.Method = "POST";
        endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
        endpointRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authenticationResult.AccessToken);
        endpointRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        Dictionary<string, object> dataFrmDb = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        dataFrmDb.Add("url", serviceRootURL + "/users/" + userPrincipalName);

        string ans = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataFrmDb);
        try
        {

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(endpointRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(ans);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }

            HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(endpointResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(endpointResponse.StatusCode.ToString() + ":" + result);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

where the variable serviceRootUrl is "https://graph.windows.net/{organization}/"

the error I get is The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: Please try to use fiddler to catch the detailed information. It will help to find out the detailed error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested to add user to AD group using Azure graph API in fiddler.

Method: POST

URL: https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/groups/cd2ddafa-d141-4b66-84ba-8673844efca5/$links/members?api-version=1.6
//guid in above link is group object ID, we could find it in Azure portal like following screenshot.

[image]

Here is my headers:

```html
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: graph.windows.net
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 111
Authorization: Bearer <your token>
```

Post Body:

```html
{
  "url": "https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/fe989a2b-81d1-48ca-aa15-0ac52688f65b"
}
```

// we could also find the user guid in azure portal too.
[image]

With above post request, I add the member to the group:
[image]

Please run your code and use fiddler to capture the traffic, then check your headers, url, post body to ensure there is no issues. You could also read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/groups-operations#AddGroupMembers) for more details about how to add user to a group via graph API.

Comment: The object Id was wrong in the code, the real problem was I was passing the name in the parameter, not the object Id... thanks I was using that same article.